# Exporting the database of Microsoft Azure wordpress web app

Tags: database, wordpress, azure, azure-web-app-service

I want to download my azure wordpress site completely including the database. I downloaded my web site using FTP login but i cant find the database.I want to know how how to access it and export the database as a .sql file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I want to download my azure wordpress site completely including the database.

Wordpress app uses MySQL database. We can choose ClearDB or MySQL In App as database provider when we create Wordpress app.

[image]

If you use ClearDB, you could get the connection string of your database from the AppSettings page of Azure portal.

[image]

If you use MySQL in app, you could use phpMyAdmin tool which is installed by default to manage your MySQL database. The URL of phpMyAdmin is,

https://[yoursitename].scm.azurewebsites.net/phpMyAdmin/

You can also open it from Azure portal.

[image]

Azure WordPress database in app is called localdb. You can export it using phpMyAdmin by clicking export button after you selected the database.

[image]

Comment: I modified my reply based on the changes of your question.

Comment: Any update? If my reply is helpful for you, please mark it as answer. A thread which has answer can be more easier searched. It will help others who encountered similar issue. If you have further questions, please feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Export a database using the Azure Portal, open the page for your database and click on Export.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-export

Comment: That's for SQL Database. Unless the OP is using a special version of WordPress that uses SQL, it's going to be a MySQL database. Which is unrelated to that post.

Answer (score -2):

I am not sure, but it may help you to get full back up with db and source from word press admin via akeeba bakup.

In which you have to mentioned path of back up and it would generate final **.jpa** file which you have to use as source and back up combination file for upload somewhere...

Please go though below link for further detail, i have used it and it was use full for me as well.

[AkeebaBack](https://www.akeebabackup.com/)

[How to migrate / back up wordpress via AkeebaBackup](https://www.themeum.com/wordpress-how-to-migrate-from-one-host-to-another/)

Comment: This question has nothing to do with promoting 3rd-party backup solutions.

Comment: @david: i am developer and not from plugin family. sorry if you feel i am promoting about plugin.but i shared my though as i experience about plugin that just from single click how entire source and db user can download in to single file, which might more helpful as OP is facing issue with DB and all that.

Comment: I wasn't saying you were related to the company. I'm saying the question is related to finding where content lives within a Web App. And there are dozens of 3rd-party products, which can be found easily, on different sites. StackOverflow isn't the place for that.